# Can't subscribe pusher private channel, getting java.io.FileNotFoundException this error every time

Tags: android, kotlin, pusher

I'm using Pusher for real-time communication in my application, and I'm trying to subscribe a private channel. However, I'm encountering an error when attempting to subscribe.

The error message I'm receiving is `com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://devapi.bdknowledgebook.com/api/broadcasting/auth`. I have already verified that the Pusher credentials, including the app key, app secret, and cluster, are correct.

What could be the possible reasons for this error, and how can I resolve it? Are there any specific configurations or permissions that need to be set up on the Pusher dashboard or in my application code to connect to a private channel successfully?

I would appreciate any insights, troubleshooting steps, or code examples that can help me resolve this issue and establish a connection to a private channel on Pusher. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**Connect to pusher**

```kotlin
private lateinit var pusher: Pusher
private fun connectPusher() {
    val parameters = HashMap<String, String>()
    parameters["Accept"] = "application/json"
    parameters["Authorization"] = sharedPrefHelper.getString(SpKey.userAuthKey)

    val channelAuthorizer = HttpChannelAuthorizer("END_POINT")
    channelAuthorizer.setHeaders(parameters)
    val options = PusherOptions().setCluster("CLUSTER").setChannelAuthorizer(channelAuthorizer)
    pusher = Pusher("APP_KEY", options)

    pusher.connect(object : ConnectionEventListener {
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(change: ConnectionStateChange) {
            Timber.e("----->State changed from ${change.previousState} to ${change.currentState}")
            if(change.currentState == ConnectionState.CONNECTED)
                subscribeChannel()
        }

        override fun onError(message: String?, code: String?, e: Exception?) {
            Timber.e("----->There was a problem connecting! code ")
        }
    }, ConnectionState.ALL)
}
```

Subscribe private channel

```kotlin
lateinit var channel : PrivateChannel
private fun subscribeChannel() {
    channel = pusher.subscribePrivate("private-message.2", object : PrivateChannelEventListener {
        override fun onEvent(event: PusherEvent?) {
            Timber.e("----->channel: ${event?.channelName} , eventName: ${event?.eventName} data: ${event?.data}")
        }

        override fun onSubscriptionSucceeded(s: String) {
            Timber.e("----->isChannelSubscribed: $s:")
            bindToEvents(channel)
        }

        override fun onAuthenticationFailure(s: String, e: Exception) {
            Timber.e("----->chSubError: $e")
        }
    })
}
```

**Bind Event**

```kotlin
private fun bindToEvents(channel : PrivateChannel){
    channel.bind("App\\Events\\NewMessage", object  : PrivateChannelEventListener{
        override fun onEvent(event: PusherEvent?) {
            Timber.e("----->eventListener-->>: $event")
        }

        override fun onSubscriptionSucceeded(channelName: String?) {
            Timber.e("----->isEventSubscribed: $channelName")
        }

        override fun onAuthenticationFailure(message: String?, e: Exception?) {
            Timber.e("----->eventSubError: $message")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/chinloyal/pusher_client/issues/25

Comment: resolved? same here